# ApiConvention response types- matching multiple Get methods

Tags: api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, conventions

I have several controllers within my project which have multiple Get methods:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<DModel>>> Get(){}
public async Task<ActionResult<DModel>> Get(int id){}
```

I am trying to create a convention which matches against these but dependent on the param - so it can tell the difference. So far I have:

```
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
        [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Prefix)]
        public static void Get()
        {
        }

        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Prefix)]
        [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
        public static void Get(
            [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Prefix)]
            int id)
        {
        }
```

This doesn't seem to work and I get an error when I try and start the API:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Method name 'Get' is ambiguous for
>   convention type 'P.API.Conventions.PApiConventions'. More than one
>   method found with the name 'Get'. Arg_ParamName_Name'

This shows against the app.UseMvc() in Startup.
I understand what happening but can't seem to work the logic to get it to resolve the get methods properly.

Comment: If you want to match different methods based on the presence of parameters, you will need to specify the parameter as part of the route. In this case, if you add either an `HttpGet` or `Route` attribute (e.g. `[HttpGet("{id:int}")]`) to your second method will help the routing engine differentiate betweenthem. See the [ASP.NET Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in the Web API conventions but during various tests I noticed that the conventions don't affect routing and model binding. So you still need to explicitly specify `HttpMethod` attribute for actions

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<DModel>>> Get(){}

//parameter name must match string inside curly braces
//if you leave {id} and update parameter name to idName
//(which matches prefix name convention)
//model binder won't bind value to parameter
//although tools that are using api conventions still will properly read controller info
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<DModel>> Get(int id){}
```